# the React project execute the eject command, after execution, I found that all the first lines of the JavaScript file will report error

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-preset-env

I use the latest create repeat app to create the React project, and then execute the eject command to expose the webpack configuration. However, after execution, I found that all the first lines of the JavaScript file will report errors, and eslint will report babel errors. Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhPoE.png)

I cleared Babel's presets as an array in 'package. json', and the error disappeared. I found that it should be the Babel preset problem, but I don't know where the problem is. The newly created project only executed an eject, and there was no problem before it was exposed. After it was exposed, I reported the error I described above. I don't understand why this is happening. Is there a problem with 'Babel preset read app'?